# How can I earn more Gems?

Tags: dragonvale

Gems are Dragonvale's premium currency. There are some awesome looking dragons I could get, but I don't have enough Gems.

Is there an in-game way to earn Gems? Or do I just have to buy them for real world money/get them as gifts?

Comment: Congrats on 11k!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only ways to get gems are to:

- Purchase them
- Get them from the tutorial
- Be given them by friends
- Share completed goals on Facebook/Twitter
- Win Colosseum matches
- Win them at the racetrack
- Acquire them from Gemstone dragons

If you just started: At several points, the tutorial will give you gems and tell you to use them. Ignore the prompts, and you'll get to keep the gems.

There is no limit on how many gems you can receive from friends, but every player can only gift 3 gems per day (6 if they have the Dragonsai Gifting Tree). So generally you can get a maximum of 3/6 gems from friends daily - unless you can find someone willing to give you gems for nothing in return.

When you complete in-game objectives called "goals", most message pop-ups will have Facebook/Twitter sharing buttons. Use both to receive 2 extra gems. Some goals themselves also have a small gem reward attached to them.

The Colosseum will win you [0/2/5 gems per day](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Colosseum#Rewards). You can enter one dragon a day, and at most you'll get 5 gems per day back as a reward.

Winning the race gives you a spin of the prize wheel - rarely, you may win some gems. Entering the race is relatively inexpensive and frequently rewards gold, so entering hundreds of times per day is not out of the question, assuming you have enough time to devote.

Every month a rare dragon is available for breeding which matches the birthstone of the month. These dragons can only live on gemstone island. When upgraded to level 10, these dragons produce gems at a rate of 1/week. By default you can have at most 12 dragons on your gemstone island, 3 per island. As Shadur notes in the comments, you can also upgrade each section of the gemstone island for 25, then 50 gems, each upgrading allowing each "quarter" of the island to hold one more dragon. You can get 12 gems a week with a fully stocked, non-upgraded gemstone island, or up to 20 gems a week with a fully upgraded gemstone island. (Note it takes a whooping 300 gems to upgrade all island slots).

Note gems are mostly for extras; speeding up actions, upgrading certain buildings (the nursery) or buying special buildings (the extra breeding cave).

Comment: And also for buying a bunch of dragon types :(

Comment: @AshleyNunn all dragons are breedable. If you can buy it, you can breed it

Comment: Gemstone island plateaus are now  upgradeable (twice, for 25 and 50 gems) to hold up to 5 dragons apiece.

Comment: @Shadur updated the answer, hopefully that's all accurate? I haven't played since they added that update, I just added info based on your comment

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Shadur but is it "worth it" to get a gem island, for a lower level player?  How quickly can one populate it with dragons?

Comment: Gemstone dragons breed very slowly and only very rarely. Consult the dragonvale wikia on which gem is in season which month, and dedicate one breeding location to constantly mating the appropriate pair in the hopes of getting the dragon.

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier by Ben - purchasing, coliseum battles and friends can get you gems.

However there is a recent addition to the game. Racing which you can interact and race the dragon you choose. When you win first, second, or third you get to spin a wheel to find out the prize you receive.

If you win first place multiple times gems will start to be a prize to show up on the wheel. I have only seen 1&2 gems on the wheel and have personally only won 1 gem at a time from spinning.

You can also get food, money, or experience from winning first, second, or third.

Answer (score 0):

Well , In order to get gems you must do these things:

1. Earn gems on dragon track or the colliseum.
2. Get gems from friends. You'll get 3 gems from your friend, 6 if they or you have the gifting tree.  So ask friends to add you on dragonvale so you can earn them!
3. Use gemstone dragons .